# Update MySQL table with counts from subquery if string match, else set to zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table `department_members` that contains rows with a string field (`member_name`) and an int field (`recent_actions`) for every person in a single department. `Recent_actions` is currently NULL for all rows.

I have another, much larger table `company_actions` that contains a row for every time someone in the whole company has performed that type of action in the past year. Each row has a `member_name, timestamp,` and a unique `action_id`.

I want to update `department_members.recent_actions` with a count of how many times that member has performed that type of action within the past two weeks. If they haven't performed any actions recently, I want to update `department_members.recent_actions` with 0.

I've tried various CASE and IF approaches, but I can't get the syntax right.

In pseudocode, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
UPDATE department_members AS d,
  (SELECT COUNT(action_id) AS recent, member_name 
      FROM company_actions 
         WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AS tmp
/* then do something like this, only for real: */
IF d.member_name IN tmp(member_names) THEN d.recent_actions = tmp.recent 
    WHERE d.member_name = tmp.member_name
ELSE IF d.member_name NOT IN tmp(member_names) THEN d.recent_actions = 0
```

Hopefully that gets across what I'm going for? Any help would be appreciated! Been beating my head against this problem all day.

Comment: [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) clause should fit the bill. Show your query with `CASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `department_members` with a subquery that calculates the total number of `action_id` in table `company_actions` using `LEFT JOIN`.

The `COALESCE()` returns the first non-null value in the *params* list.

```
UPDATE  department_members a
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  member_name, COUNT(*) TotalAction
            FROM    company_actions
            WHERE   timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
            GROUP   BY member_name
        ) b ON a.member_name = b.member_name
SET     a.action_id = COALESCE(b.TotalAction, 0)
```